# Как вытащить определённый id через ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Нужно вытаскивать определённый id товара. Но не знаю как связать js и php, да и вроде как это не возможно, поэтому прошу помочь с вопросом как передать id страницы(он же id товара), чтобы вытянуть нужный мне товар.

```
var counter = 0;
function addto()
{
    var counter_same_product = 0;

    var id = $(".product-image-wrapp").attr("data-id");
    var product_data = new Array();

    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "../assets/php/product_get_item.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {product_data: product_data},
        async: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
            product_data = data;
        }
    })


    console.log(product_data);

    var serialObj = JSON.stringify(product_data);
    localStorage.setItem("product", serialObj);
    var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("product"));



    counter_same_product++;
    counter++;
    localStorage.setItem("counter", counter);
}
```

php

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM products";


$sql = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

$arr = array("id" => $result["id"],
             "name" => $result["product_name"],
             "description" => $result["product_description"],
             "price" => $result["price"],
             "size" => $result["product_size"],
             "type" => $result["type"]
            );

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

мой урл(mysite.ru/pages/product-cart?id=2)

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Нужные вам данные передаете ajax запросом и ловите их на стороне PHP. Т.е. в теле ajax запроса добавляете  `$.ajax( ....type: "GET", data: {'product_id' : id //тут подставляете нужное значение ... }`. Потом в php файле смотрите что пришло `var_dump($_GET)`

Comment: сделал так, но ничего не происходит, в php переменная не попадает, пишет NULL

Comment: А если открыть инструмент разработчика(обычно кнопка F12) выбрать вкладку `Network` отправить запрос, выбрать отправленный запрос в левом окне и посмотреть `Form Data` этого запроса. Что там показывается? Вот пример:  https://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=6d67f850fe4e987bf5b168b811152886

Comment: Не знаю как тут прикрепить картинки поэтому вот так: https://ibb.co/SQW21Y8
https://ibb.co/Jz4R0tB

Comment: Он вроде как что-то отправляет, но не получает

Comment: Все разобрался. Снизу прикреплю код, может у кого такая же проблема будет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function getUrlValue(varName) {  //Функция для получения значения переменной в URL
    var split = $(location).attr('href').split('?');
    var value = '';
    if (split.length == 2) {
        split = split[1].split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i+=1) {
            var keyValue = split[i].split('=');
            if (keyValue.length == 2 && keyValue[0] == varName) {
                value = keyValue[1];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return value;
}   


var counter = 0;
function addto()  // Функция добавления в корзину
{
    var counter_same_product = 0;

    var id = getUrlValue("id");
    var product_data = new Array();

    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "../assets/php/product_get_item.php?id="+id, // передаем переменную в php script
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        data: {'product_data' : id},
        async: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
            product_data = data;
        }
    })


    console.log(product_data);

    var serialObj = JSON.stringify(product_data);
    localStorage.setItem("product", serialObj);
    var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("product"));



    counter_same_product++;
    counter++;
    localStorage.setItem("counter", counter);
}
```

JS

```
<?
    require_once("connect.php");


    $id = $_GET["id"]; // Получаем отправленную переменную


    $query = "SELECT * FROM products where id=".$id; //Выбираем все продукты с данным id


    $sql = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

    $arr = array("id" => $result["id"], // Создаем массив данных о продукте
                 "name" => $result["product_name"],
                 "description" => $result["product_description"],
                 "price" => $result["price"],
                 "size" => $result["product_size"],
                 "type" => $result["type"]
                );

    echo json_encode($arr); // генерируем массив для отправки в LocalStorage
?>
```

php